# Remote Procedure Call (RPC) in C++: Can multiple Clients listen to one server when endpoint is hard coded?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, rpc, midl

I'm writing a simple server-client using `MIDL` and `RPC` to allow file transferring. 
It works when endpoint is hard coded as follow:

server side

```
status = RpcServerUseProtseqEp(  
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>("ncacn_ip_tcp"), 
    RPC_C_PROTSEQ_MAX_REQS_DEFAULT,                   
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>("8888"),         
    NULL);
```

Client Side

```
status = RpcStringBindingCompose(NULL,
    "ncacn_ip_tcp",
    (RPC_CSTR)"127.0.0.1", 
    "8888",
    NULL,
    NULL);
```

I'm wondering if multiple clients are able to connect to one server when endpoint is hard coded? As we know that in socket programming using TCP protocol, two application cannot connect to a single port at one time. However, the `MSDN` reference says that `RPC` server process uses a first-in, first-out call queue to handle requests.

If it is unable to receive multiple requests from clients, is there a way to set an endpoint pool?  Thank you.

Comment: Usually servers listen to clients for requests. Do you want to check this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the terminology here.

The *server* is listening on a TCP port. That means it binds to the port and starts the accept loop on it. Every time that a new client *connects* to this port, the accept function establishes a TCP *connection* with that client, and goes back to listening on the port.

The server application is either a multi-threaded or an asynchronous application that handles *multiple actions* simultaneously: listening for new clients, communicating with each connected client and performing the actual work.

A typical RPC server would look something like

```
status = RpcServerUseProtseqEp(pszProtocolSequence,
                               RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,
                               pszEndpoint,
                               pszSecurity); 

if (status) exit(status);

status = RpcServerRegisterIf(my_rpc_interface_spec,  
                             NULL,   
                             NULL); 

if (status) exit(status);

status = RpcServerListen(cMinCalls,
                         RPC_C_LISTEN_MAX_CALLS_DEFAULT,
                         0);

if (status) exit(status);
```

The `RpcServerListen` call would block forever, start `cMinCalls` worker threads and perform the `accept` loop, accepting the connections and handling the requests in up to `cMinCalls` parallel threads.